# How to change sound indicator player's icons size

Tags: sound, icons, indicator, resize

Where can I change the size of icons in the portion of volume control? [view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdXip.png)

Comment: you should probably mention what theme you're using

Comment: @doug, all themes has the same problem.

Comment: I got the same problem and i'm using FS icon theme on Ubuntu 16.04. https://launchpad.net/fs-icons-ubuntu

Comment: I have figured it out and in my case I unable to find any icons for VLC, Rhythembox and SMPlayer in my theme. I think theme inherit some icons from another theme. Using gimp I have modified some icons for above application and re-sized into various sizes (16,22,24,32,48,64,128) and apply it to my theme. And then my problem solved. I think adding 16x16,22x22,24x24,32x32 size icon to your themes app dir will solve the issue.